# What are the benefits & drawbacks of using properties files in java project and what are the alternatives of properties file?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

My project is accessing many properties file and there are so many more properties files be added in. Can any please the benefits & drawbacks of using properties files in java project and what alternatives of properties file I can use in my project.

Comment: Properties are simple, sometime too simple.  It depends on what you want to do.  However, unless you have a good reason not to, I would start with the simplest approach and change it later if you have to.  If you have a Properties file large enough to be worried about performance you shouldn't be using Properties.

Comment: Can you say what your performance requirements are?

Comment: You can just guess that dozens of "you can use a database" answers/comments are pending. Why exactly is the "performance" tag on this question?

Comment: Thanks, all.. Actually the thread of my project  is accessing many properties very much frequently and DB is always reliable then File IO, so  I want to switch to DB. Is it right?